# where does the pointer created by new get deleted in this code?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I am reading the [IB api C++ code](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/?f=%2Fen%2Fsoftware%2Fibapi.php&ns=T), and have found the following class structure

```
class EWrapper;

class EClientSocketBase{
 public:
 EClientSocketBase( EWrapper *ptr): m_pEWrapper(ptr){}
 ~EClientSocketBase(){ }
 // some methods
 private:
 EWrapper *m_pEWrapper;
 // some other data members
};

class EPosixClientSocket : public EClientSocketBase{
// some methods and data members
EPosixClientSocket( EWrapper *ptr) : EClientSocketBase( ptr){}
~EPosixClientSocket(){}
};

class PosixTestClient : public EWrapper{
public:
PosixTestClient(): m_pClient(new EPosixClientSocket(this)){}
~PosixTestClient(){}
// some other methods 
private:
std::auto_ptr<EPosixClientSocket> m_pClient;
// some other methods and data members
};
```

I feel very uncomfortable about this code, especially on not putting `delete` the pointer `m_pEWrapper` in the destructor  of `EClientSocketBase`, and more uncomfortable about the initializing `EPosixClientSocket` with `this`, but somehow I can not articulate what exactly the mistake is.

1. A question to ask is that where the pointer `m_pClient`, and pointer `m_pEWrapper` get deleted respectively? Should you put `delete m_pEWrapper` in the destructor of `EClientSocketBase`?
2. Is there something wrong in this code? If yes, what is it? If not, is it a good practice to write code like this?

Comment: Regarding question (1): my guess is the designer of `EClientSocketBase` chose to simply **use** an instance of `EWrapper` rather than take **ownership** of it, which is why you don't see it being freed.  If that's the case, a better choice would have been to use a member variable of type `EWrapper&` rather than `EWrapper*` to better convey this decision (in lieu of good documentation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's [`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr)'s job. It is:

> a smart pointer that manages an object obtained via new expression and **deletes that object when `auto_ptr` itself is destroyed**.

So in `~PosixTestClient()`, when `m_pClient` gets destroyed, it will `delete` the pointer that it is managing. This is far safer than taking care of calling `delete` yourself.

---

Note that in C++11, `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated in favor of [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which is a strictly superior alternative.